# Correct terminology for object "elements" in R

Tags: r, list, terminology

Lists are composed of elements. I think that is the correct terminology. Or are they called components? For example,

```
list(c("row1", "row2"), c("C.1", "C.2", "C.3")))
```

has 2 elements (components?). What is the correct terminology for the components of an element?

This is the first (and only) component of the first element

```
[1] "row1" "row2"
```

This is the first (and only) component of the second element

```
[1] "C.1" "C.2" "C.3"
```

Is this the correct terminology? Elements composed of components? Or what is the right way to say this? Also, where would I look to find the official terminology for this kind of thing?

Comment: What is your programming problem?

Comment: [This](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Lists) could help.

Comment: @ANG, thanks for link. Wow, it seems that there is no proper terminology! What I saw there was, "gives the number of (top level) components" and so I assume that we have to use terms like "components of components". Not so great I think.

Comment: You're welcome! I think one the most important things one must remember is that "an R list is **an object consisting of an ordered collection of objects** known as its components" and that **there is no particular need for the components to be of the same type**". PS: List components are also objects.

Comment: @ANG, right. I saw that and it is the most important part but reading on I realized that there is not really any terminology for the components of a component. By the way, you used the word "object". Is there a sense that these objects have methods? I recently read somewhere that that terminology, the terminology of "objects" in R is not really the same as in other languages. Do you agree?

Comment: I mainly know R so I cannot really talk about "objects" from other programming languages. But in R, the idea is that any entities R operates on are objects and each object has a particular class for which some methods can be used. For example, `methods(class = "data.frame")` will return methods (or functions) that can be used for an object of class `data.frame`.

Comment: @MLavoie I am curious why this question can't be asked here while we do have "terminology" tag in SO.

Comment: @jogo I don't think a question has to be related to programming to be asked here. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Hi, would you consider accepting my answer if that solves your original question? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both "element" and "component" express the idea. I don't think either one is official or formal. For example, [Data structures](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html) chapter in *Advanced R* uses the term "element" multiple times, but you can't find "component". Still, [the documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Lists) @ANG gives does suggest "component" could be original.

As to your case, the list `list(c("row1", "row2"), c("C.1", "C.2", "C.3"))` has two elements, and both elements are vectors:

1. `c("row1", "row2")`
2. `c("C.1", "C.2", "C.3")`

Until now you are correct.

However, the first element of that list, the vector `c("row1", "row2")`, has **two elements, `"row1"` and `"row2"`**. The same concept applies to `c("C.1", "C.2", "C.3")`, which is the second element of that list and **has three elements** in the vector.

In addition, to understand what an object is in R, let me quote John Chambers:

> Everything that exists is an object. Everything that happens is a function call.

Comment: @ANG Thanks again. I am not sure that the esteemed John Chambers was using the term object in the standard way. I don't think R is hardcore OOP but I am not sure really. I tried what ANG suggested, methods(class = "data.frame"), and the collection of functions returned did not seem to be in the definition of data.frame. Perhaps these methods are inherited from some higher level class, I am not sure. Regarding the term element in Advanced R, the fact that it is used leads me to believe there is no standard terminology (which is unfortunate).

Comment: On the other hand, faced with the problem of coming up with such terminology, it may be difficult because of the extreme flexibility of lists. You can have lists of lists of lists of lists I guess. Not sure how to go about designing a good terminology in light of this.

Comment: @onyourmark the class of objects aren't defined during the creation but with `setClass` function. The methods you saw from `methods(class = "data.frame")` are all independent functions in R. For instance, `unique` includes `unique.data.frame` and `unique.array` etc. Hence you can use `unique` function on both classes data.frame and array, and both data.frame and array have a method called "unique". I am not sure whether it's standard OOP though.

Comment: @onyourmark you are right, we can have lists of lists of lists of lists, but in practice few people would create and store data in such way. Besides, elements can have respective names so you can just call them with names if you really need it.